# numberDisplay valueAccessor in DC.js seems to round the return value

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

What I am looking for is to stop the rounding.
In this example https://jsfiddle.net/v0rdoyrt/2/ the real value from the `.valueAccessor` whenever the dataset is above `1000 or 2000 ...` is round up to `1k` or `2..k`.
How to turn that off? I have tried `.toFixed()` and other Javascript method but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for `numberDisplay.formatNumber`?

http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.numberDisplay.html#formatNumber__anchor